# Microsoft Excel Search Engine - Hyperlink Results Provides Error Message

Tags: vba, excel, hyperlink

I've been trying for two days to figure out this problem.

I have created an Excel search engine to search through a database of hyperlinks in the same worksheet. I want the results to display working hyperlinks, but right now it just displays the text. When the hyperlink is clicked, I get an error message - "Cannot open the specified file."

Can someone please help me. I've tried multiple codes including the following:

`=HYPERLINK("#"&VLOOKUP(D5,A2:C91,3,FALSE),"""")))` to no avail.

I can also email the spreadsheet if a email is provided. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

A hyperlink cannot start with the `#` sign. If the link is to a file, then you need to start with the file path, like shown in the Excel help

`=HYPERLINK("D:\FINANCE\1stqtr.xlsx", H10)`

If the link goes to another sheet in the same file, use

`=HYPERLINK("[Budget.xlsx]E56", E56)`

The Vlookup will need to return the correct file path or a valid URL, including the "http://"

Comment: Hi Teylyn,
Thanks for your help. However, my issue is I have a search engine created so the hyperlink is for the results. Is there a way I can send you the file/screenshot that shows what I'm trying to do? Thanks!

Comment: Use a file sharing service and post the link. It does not matter if the hyperlink is for the results of something. What matters is that it needs to be in the correct format.